# HTML5 Canvas: draw is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to follow the Mozilla HTML5 Canvas tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage). but I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: draw is not defined
```

I have my script as such:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="application/javascript">
$(function() {

function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
      }
    }


});

</script>


</head>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="main" width="150" height="150"></canvas>


</body>
```

I have experimented with placing the scripts both before and after the canvas element, but I get no change.

Would anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Please share your full source code; 'cause there's nothing wrong with the above. Make sure your `draw()` function is defined in the `<head> section` of your page. Otherwise onload event wont find it!

Comment: @Eric Ive added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mis-using the jQuery here. Now your draw() method is only available (and declared) in the ready() method called by jQuery. Make the function global, and skip the jQuery part.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
      }
  }
</script>
```

You see the `$(function(){ ... });` is a short-hand for the `$(document).ready()`, which are used as a call-back when all DOM-elements are loaded. In your case that is not needed, since your draw() method is called by the body onload event anyways! :-)

Comment: Ah I see - so as soon as the body loads (onload) it triggers the function? Is this the only way to do this with Canvas?

Comment: You need to make sure your DOM-tree is loaded (your site that is), before calling the draw() method. Either you do this, or you can call the draw() method inside the `$(function() { ... });`. Make sure your draw-method always is globally defined however.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the above answer could be to quit using the inline call to `draw()` and remove the function header so it directly goes into it on load.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
      }
});
</script>
```

Then your body will be freed:

```
<body>
<canvas id="main" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<!-- ... -->
```